# how to add months to this date i get

Tags: php

$date = explode("/",$_POST['datum1']); 
// format is dd/mm/yyyy then use the below

$date_customer = $date[0];

let suppose i enter 4-1-2011, it will insert only 4 in the database by using insert query but now i want to add one month to it.
mean if i enter 4th jan it inserts this, but wat wil be the code for inserting 4th Feb. date, 4th March and so on from the same input that is 4th jan ??

Comment: For me your question is not clear. could you more specify what you have and what you want?

Comment: i hv used javascript calender that will get the input date. then i had used explode function in order to get only day (ignoring month and year). and insert it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

To add a month, you can use `strtotime` function something like this:

```
$mydate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', $yourDate));
```

Or you can use MySQL's [`ADDDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) function directly in your query like this:

```
ADDDATE(yourDateField, 1 Month)
```

Comment: its a function for adding one month to date which is in date formate but i want to add a month to somewhat like int :(

Comment: @Syed, Sarfraz is correct, just assemble the '+1 month' from your int.  Like: $months_to_add = 2; $future_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$months_to_add.' month', $yourDate));

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably work better like this:

```
$yourDate = "2012-10-05";
$mydate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($yourDate)));
```